# Loop through two DOMNodeLists at once using DOMDocument class

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, domdocument

I got an error saying

> Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string on line

This is the line which contains the error:

```
$output .= '<li><a target="_blank" href="' . $postURL . '">' . 
$title->nodeValue . '</a></li>';
```

DOM

[image]

My code:

```
$postTitle = $xpath->query("//tr/td[@class='row1'][3]//span[1]/text()");
$postURL = $xpath->query("//tr/td[@class='row1'][3]//a/@href");

$output = '<ul>';

foreach ($postTitle as $title) {

        $output .= '<li><a target="_blank" href="' . $postURL . '">' . $title->nodeValue . '</a></li>';

}

$output .= '</ul>';

echo $output;
```

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: @AmalMurali the link didn't match the topic, my logic wrong?

Comment: I used evaluate, but manage to get only 1 value.

Comment: @AmalMurali if it become string, how can it loop? pls don't simply mark my question as duplicate.

Comment: It is a duplicate. Your logic is incorrect. You're trying to loop through two DOMNodeList objects at once. Store the values into two separate arrays and loop through them with a `for` loop. See [this demo](https://eval.in/155611).

Comment: @AmalMurali I got only 1 item.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to include more details and your current code that doesn't work. Explain the problem clearly and state how your question is different from the duplicate linked. Then it can be reopened.

Comment: @AmalMurali I guess you did not see my DOM (image), I have to put link because I don't have privilege to upload it.

Comment: I've reopened the question. You might want to add the actual markup instead of an image.

Answer (score 1):

You're fetching two independent node list from the DOM, iterate the first and try to use the second one inside the loop as a string. A DOMNodeList can not be cast to string (in PHP) so you get an error. Node lists can be cast to string in Xpath however.

You need to iterate the location path that is the same for booth list (`//tr/td[@class='row1'][3]`) and get the $title and $url inside the loop for each of the `td` elements.

```
$posts = $xpath->evaluate("//tr/td[@class='row1'][3]");

$output = '<ul>';
foreach ($posts as $post) {
  $title = $xpath->evaluate("string(.//span[1])", $post);
  $url = $xpath->evaluate("string(.//a/@href)", $post);
  $output .= sprintf(
    '<li><a target="_blank" href="%s">%s</a></li>',
    htmlspecialchars($url),
    htmlspecialchars($title)
  );
}
$output .= '</ul>';

echo $output;
```